# delete data when user click yes POPOVER CONFIRMATION

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

i am using Bootstrap plugin for on-place confirm boxes using Popover. I want to delete a record when user click yes button. How can I do that?
[link](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/) for Bootstrap plugin

- Bəli -means yes
- Eminsen? - are you sure?
- SİL - delete

my button

```
  <a href="#" id="@applicant.Id"  class="btn btn-outline purple-sharp  uppercase" data-btn-ok-label="Bəli"  data-toggle="confirmation"  data-placement="right" data-original-title="" title="Are you sure?" aria-describedby="confirmation64993">

                                    <i class="fa fa-trash" ></i> Delete
                                </a>
```

[image]

Comment: What record do you want to delete ?

Comment: I have id="@applicant.Id" attribute @edisoni.1337

Comment: You want to delete that from database or DOM ? Explain it a little bit more please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="@applicant.Id"  class="btn btn-outline purple-sharp  uppercase delete-confirmation" data-btn-ok-label="Bəli"  data-toggle="confirmation"  data-placement="right" data-original-title="" title="Are you sure?" aria-describedby="confirmation64993">

      <i class="fa fa-trash" ></i> Delete
</a>

// You should replace the deleteElement() function with your code
<script>
    $('.delete-confirmation').confirmation({
         onConfirm: function(event) {
              deleteElement();
         }      
    });
</script>
```